# dev c++ не видит winmm.lib

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

int main()
{
     PlaySound(TEXT("1111.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
     Sleep(3000);
}
```

Выдает такую ошибку

> [Linker error] undefined reference to `PlaySoundA@12'

Перелопатил инет, многие говорят, что dev не видит файл winmm.lib и в этом корень зла... 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что тут можно сделать?
Заранее огромное СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 1):

Так он видит или нет? `winmm` - это часть Microsoft SDK и как минимум, SDK должен быть развернут.

Comment: ошибки о том что файл не найден он не выводит.. 
что именно тут не так я не знаю. а то что не видит я просто читал в инете и так говорят почти все в данной ситуации

Comment: и еще. winmm.lib я скопировал прям в папку с проэктом, и чтоб наверняка прописал её в настройках сборщика в проэкте